# Resize box to fit text

Tags: boxes

I would like to have a box which changes width depending on the text in it. Shorter sentences should have a narrow box, and as the sentence gets longer the box should grow (until it is as wide as the text, then I would like a line break). Font size should not be affected. The best solution I've got so far (see below) scales the text when it is short.

```
\ovalbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\columnwidth}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{Some variable-length text}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `\fbox{text}`?

Comment: I do mean exactly that, thank you. Is there a way to make it oval as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put a frame around text with the `\fbox` command:

```
\fbox{text}
```

To put text in an ellipse, you can use the [TikZ/PGF](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package and its `shapes.geometric` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

% You can also make a \newcommand for this
\tikz[baseline=(e.base)] \node[ellipse,draw] (e) {text};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in both cases the text acts as one "big" box relative to the paragraph and *will not* be broken in separate lines.

If you wish to typeset whole paragraphs in a frame that does not expand to full line width if the paragraph fits on one line, then the following approach (inspired by `\@makecaption`) might do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varbox}[1]{%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-0.8pt\relax}%
  \sbox{\@tempboxa}{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\@tempdima
    \fbox{\parbox{\@tempdima}{\strut #1}}%
  \else
    \fbox{\strut #1}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\varbox{\lipsum[2]}

\noindent\varbox{not too much text}

\end{document}
```

Typesetting large blocks inside ellipses does not seem practical to me.

Comment: If you want line breaking, you could put a `\parbox` inside the `\fbox`.

Comment: @RyanReich: Yes, but this does not solve the problem of integrating the text in a paragraph, such that it begins on one line and ends on another. (This only makes sense for the frame, not the ellipse.)

Comment: Ah, I understood the breaking request in the question to mean that the box would constitute an independent paragraph.  It seems like it would be very difficult to get a flowed frame inside a paragraph; for example, how would it look if there were a gap between the end of the text on the second line and the beginning of the text on the first line?

Answer (score 10):

You may also have a look at the [`varwidth` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth). It allows to define a environment `{varwidth}` which behaves like a `{minipage}` but takes a *maximum* width as argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

% just for this demo
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\fbox{%
    \begin{varwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
    Text
    \end{varwidth}%
}

Text that deomenstrates the \verb|\textwidth|, an for that is
longer than one line or maybe two.

\fbox{%
    \begin{varwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
    Very long text, that breaks a line.
    Very long text, that breaks a line.
    Very long text, that breaks a line.
    \end{varwidth}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 7):

You should also consider [the `mdframed` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed). In the case where you have large passages this will actually work across page breaks, and a lot of flexibility in terms of line styles, fill color, etc...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=15pt, linecolor=red, outerlinewidth=2pt,backgroundcolor=yellow!30]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\columnwidth}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{Some variable-length text}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, how can I forget the obvious!

Comment: I have gotten so used to using `mdframed`, that using a simple `fbox` would probably not have occurred to me. :-)