# Boxes overflow column

Tags: line-breaking, boxes

It's all in the subject.
I used all kinds of boxes in a `towcolumn` article, but whenever the boxed text is long enough, the box happily continues into the other column!

Is there a "smart" box that "follows" the text, like the blue one aroung URLs ?
Sample document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,twocolumn,english]{article} 
\begin{document}  
\fbox{Alpha particles (named after and denoted by the first letter in the
Greek alphabet) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
together.
This means that an  particle is a helium nucleus. }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you like to explain better what you mean with "boxed text"?

Comment: Maybe provide a minimal working example. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: `\mbox` is indivisible by design.

Comment: @donc_oe: added a sample.

Comment: @ExpertNoob I don't think this is a particularly good way to emphasize some text. To be honest, I find it a *bad* way to emphasize text.

Answer (score 6):

This is too long for a comment: I think that an image will convince you desisting from this project.

[image]

The result is undoubtedly awful.

---

On the serious side, here's a simple way to frame something in a better fashion.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for the mock text

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mdframed}[
  leftmargin=\parindent,
  rightmargin=\parindent,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep
  ]
  \emph{Alpha particles} (named after
    and denoted by the first letter in the Greek
alphabet) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
together. This means
that a particle is a helium nucleus.
\end{mdframed}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need ! How can I get this ?

Comment: @ExpertNoob Sorry. I want to sleep at night without being obsessed by the spirits of Gutenberg, Manuzio, Tschichold and others seeking for revenge. `:)`

Comment: @ExpertNoob Oh, I had hoped that in spite of mentioning the `hyperref` box you are not exactly looking for a one-line-height box. Well, you might nevertheless consider my answer, which I think is a much more pleasant way of boxing text.

Comment: @egreg High five for edit timing and +1 for the high-level version.

Comment: @egreg: I've done my research before asking, and I'm now pretty knowledgeable about all things framed. I am specifically looking for the "line-following" box like on your first image. Can I have the source for that please ?

Answer (score 5):

Here are two solutions that keep the `\fbox`. The text to be framed is wrapped by a `\parbox` to ensure line breaks, and indentation is adjusted. The first variant keeps the column line width for the text. Consequently, it will result in an overfull `\hbox`, which you may or may not mind. Alternatively, the width of the `\parbox` can be adjusted such that the `\fbox` exactly fits into `\linewidth`, which is shown in the right column.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\raggedbottom       %don't stretch space between paragraphs to fill columns
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\defaultparindent
\setlength{\defaultparindent}{\parindent}   %save default indentation   

\begin{document}
\section{Section}

\lipsum[75]
\vspace{\dimexpr.8pt+\fboxsep\relax}        %add interline space

%Version 1
{%group to keep \parindent change local
    \parindent-\fboxsep     %revert indentation due to \fbox frame space
    \indent%    
    \fbox{%
        \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \parindent\defaultparindent%
        \indent Alpha particles (named after and denoted by the first letter in the Greek alphabet) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
    together. This means that an  particle is a helium nucleus.}}
}%end parindent group

\vspace{\dimexpr.8pt+\fboxsep\relax}    

\lipsum[1]
\pagebreak
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{\dimexpr.8pt+\fboxsep\relax}

%Version 2
\noindent       
\fbox{%
    \parbox{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-1.6pt}{%
    \parindent\defaultparindent%
    \indent Alpha particles (named after and denoted by the first letter in the Greek alphabet) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
together. This means that an  particle is a helium nucleus.}}

\vspace{\dimexpr.8pt+\fboxsep\relax}

\lipsum[75]     
  \end{document}
```

Comment: This solution has the merit of not needing any package. It's possible to avoid warnings with the first way, but I'd go with the second.

Comment: I'd choose either the first or a larger indent, as in your solution, since with no indent being the reader's reference level, a too narrow indent may be perceived as "wrong" rather than intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
This is \texthl{a very, very, very, very, in fact, an obscenely long
  and considerably friendly text}, my friend.
\end{document}
```

You'll find that the basic mechanism of the `soul` package used for text highlighting is required also for framed texts that are supposed to linewrap: the bulk of linewrapped boxes consists of an overline and an underline at fixed height.  I actually have a hard time imagining this kind of construct with borders looking nice in a linewrapped context, but it sounds like this is what you are after.  When the boxes do not appear in mid-line but as containers/blocks of their own, the `framed` package will offer a variety of styles.

Comment: Thanks, that can be useful. But I'm really after a frame, not background coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I could find is [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45170/resize-box-to-fit-text)'s `varbox` (using `\columnwidth` instead of `\linewidth` + some customization for tighter boxes):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varbox}[1]{%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\columnwidth\relax}%
  \sbox{\@tempboxa}{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\@tempdima
    \begingroup\fboxsep=0.6mm
      \fbox{\parbox{\@tempdima}{\strut #1}}%
    \endgroup
    \vspace{\dimexpr-2pt\relax}
  \else
    \begingroup\fboxsep=0.4mm
      \fbox{\strut #1} 
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
```