# How to highlight an entire paragraph?

Tags: color, boxes, paragraphs, highlighting

I'd like to highlight paragraphs such that the highlight color appears as one whole rectangle underlying the entire paragraph. I have looked around but nothing gives me the desired effect so far.

For example `\fcolorbox{}` from `xcolor` cannot highlight an entire paragraph; `\hl{}` from `soul` leaves out spacings between lines uncolored.

I am wondering how I can do this?

Comment: use package `mdframed`. You'll get the documentation with running `texdoc mdframed`

Comment: See also: http://marcodaniel.github.com/mdframed/

Comment: The answers to yesterday's [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59175/boxes-overflow-column) show how to achieve an uncoloured frame.

Comment: Sorry. Wanted to show how to accomplish that in HTML, but the board does not handle styles.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here's a list of other possible solutions

1. A solution that admits page breaks using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[4]
   \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
   \lipsum[2]
   \end{mdframed}
   \lipsum[4]

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   The environments provided by the `mdframed` package are highly customizable so, for example, using the `(inner)leftmargin`, `(inner)rightmargin` options, you can produce this (the textwidth remains unaltered and the frame extends a little into the margins):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[4]
   \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20,innerleftmargin=3pt,innerrightmargin=3pt,leftmargin=-3pt,rightmargin=-3pt]
   \lipsum[2]
   \end{mdframed}
   \lipsum[4]

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Here's now a solution using the [`framed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package and its `shaded` environment; this solution also admits page breaks:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{framed}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[4]
   \begin{shaded}
   \lipsum[2]
   \end{shaded}
   \lipsum[4]

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. Now a solution using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package; this solution admits page breaks inside `tcolorbox` if you load the `breakable` library and use the `breakable` key:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{tcolorbox}
   \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[4]
   \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,notitle,boxrule=0pt,colback=blue!20,colframe=blue!20]
   \lipsum[2-20]
   \end{tcolorbox}
   \lipsum[4]

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
4. A solution using the [adjustbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package (no page breaks allowed):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{adjustbox}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[4]

   \noindent\adjustbox{bgcolor=blue!20,minipage=[t]{\linewidth}}{\lipsum[4]}

   \lipsum[4]

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
5. And finally, one solution using the [`fancypar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancypar) package (this solution won't accept page breaks either):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fancypar}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[4]
   \ZebraPar[colorone=blue!20,colortwo=blue!20]{\lipsum[4]}
   \lipsum[4]

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Another option would be  where the box extends slightly into the margins so that the paragraph flow does not get altered.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes; I added a note about the flexibility of `mdframed` and a new example.

Comment: Can you provide a small list of packages. For example: `adjustbox`, `tcolorbox` and `framed`. I think all packages have their advantages.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yes; it's a god idea. I've updated my answer with a list of examples using various packages.

Comment: Feedback for a recent recent TeXlive installation. `framed` approach: the `shadecolor` is not a valid identifier anymore. `mdframed` approach: it changes the paragraph indentation in the first line (w/o mdframed env the first line is indented, w/ mdframed it is not).

Comment: The link to the `framed` package points to tcolorbox instead.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Thanks for noticing it. I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 19):

A combination of `\colorbox` and a `\parbox` works, as long as your paragraph doesn't need to be broken over pages. That won't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\colorbox{yellow}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}% a box with line-breaks that's just wide enough
        {% your paragraph here:
        \lipsum[1]%
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The overfull box can be avoided very simple by `\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Nice solution to the overfull box :-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks, I included that. So `\dimexpr` means something like "calculate the following"? Where would I find an explanation of such macros? I didn't find anything in `latex2e` nor in `macros2e`.

Comment: @doncherry those are e-TeX macros: `texdoc etex`.

Answer (score 11):

Is the [`todonotes`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) package a possiblity? If so, [*Highlighting a Paragraph in LaTeX*](http://www.multiasking.com/2010/07/highlighting-a-paragraph-in-latex/) by Hinnerk Brügmann provides a solution.
For some reason or the other the `lipsum` package didn't work well with it. The user provides the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bordercolor=white,backgroundcolor=gray!30,linecolor=black,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\newcommand{\rework}[1]{%
\todo[color=yellow,inline]{Rework: {#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
%------------------------------
% Update suggested by @Fran
%------------------------------
\rework{\protect\lipsum[2]}
%------------------------------
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]