# Frame over multicol columnbreak

Tags: multicol, framed, mdframed

Hello everybody out there using TeX,

Is there a possibility to draw a frame over a columnbreak when using for example the `multicol` package?

I've already tried several possibilities and done extensive websearch.
Interestingly, there seem to be several people having this problem, but there's no solution available in the web.

Unfortunately, the `framed` and `mdframed` package don't work with the `multicol` package according to their manuals.

The listings package, seems to have a bug: it does split text on different columns correctly, but the colour highlights wrong sections:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color,lipsum,listings,multicol}
\lstset{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{green},
  escapechar={\%}
}
\begin{document}
   \begin{multicols*}{4}
     \colorbox{green}{
     \begin{lstlisting}
       %
       \section{First section}
       \lipsum
       %
     \end{lstlisting}
     }
   \end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

I would be very grateful for any hints towards a solution.

One additional step in the right direction might be the `boites` package:

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}
\usepackage{boites,color,lipsum,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{breakbox}
\lipsum
\end{breakbox}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But this does not allow for background colouring using pdflatex.

Comment: What do you mean with "draw a frame over a columnbreak"?

Comment: I believe the question is related to the \colorbox{} - how to make it automatically split between columns instead of being in it's total height either at the end of column 1 or at the top of column 2. (I do have the same problem.) Or more generic: how to have a multi-line box with border or background color split in half when necessary.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color,lipsum,multicol}
\advance\columnsep3pt
\makeatletter
\def\foo#1\full@width#2#3!!{
\def\page@sofar{#1\full@width{%
\vrule
{\color{green}\leaders\vrule\hskip\full@width}\kern-\full@width
\kern3\p@
#2%
 \kern3\p@\vrule}%
#3}}
\expandafter\foo\page@sofar!!

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

   \begin{multicols*}{4}
       \section{First section}
       \lipsum
   \end{multicols*}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Werner commented in chat that this answer was less than completely documented.

`\page@sofar` is the `multicol` internal macro responsible for assembing the column boxes that have been produced into a row across the page together with inter-column rules and space. this just inserts a black rule and some space either side. (The `\intercolumnsep` parameter is increased a bit to make space for these) and a full width green rule is added at the start of the box, then negative space inserted so the column boxes come on top.

Comment: why not patch a little bit more "high-level" using etoolbox or so? very efficient above, but probably not understandable to many without a lot of thinking.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach feel free to edit my answer:-) I'd have to check the etoolbox patch syntax but can write the delimited argument form in my sleep. But yes it would be better, I should try harder:-)

Comment: it wouldn't hurt if you do :-) it is easy enough ... but I know the feeling ... had a copy of the code lying around for cut and paste from one answer to the next for a while