# How to seamlessy color the background of a series of \items

Tags: lists, color, backgrounds

I need to change the background of a number of (full) `\item`s in a numbered list. I saw the answers to [How to highlight an entire paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph) and (naively) tried to do the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newcommand{\blob}{A text which is long, but not so long  as a
  \texttt{\textbackslash lipsum}  paragraph and show the
  problem about changing the background color}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \blob
  \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
  \item \blob
  \item \blob
  \end{mdframed}
  \item \blob
  \item \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
        \blob   \end{mdframed} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, that does not work. The first `mdframed` simply stop the listng, and the second way of using it has a strange effect:

[image: Example rendering]

I would like to have just the background change, without changing the list spacing. The change of background *will* happen sometime across a page break.

I tried to use the method proposed in [Box around a few items in an itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45912), but that method has two shortcomings for my application:

- (minor) it can just highlight one section in the list --- if I need a couple of them it doesn't work;
- (major) does not work if the highlighted text cross a page boundary.

Next I tried to suspend and resume the list, but it gave me other problems:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed,xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}
\newcommand{\blob}{A text which is long, but not so long  as a
  \texttt{\textbackslash lipsum}  paragraph and show the
  problem about starting and resuming lists multiple times}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \blob
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{shaded}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item \blob
    \item \blob
  \end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item \blob
    \item last one
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It seemed a good idea, but intermixing the `shaded` environment mangles the `[resume]` option (probably due to locality of definitions into the `shaded` environment):

[image: Other failed try...]

Comment: Related, if not duplicate question: [Box around a few items in an itemize environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45912)

Comment: I edited the question after trying your suggestion --- it does not work across pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is room for improvement, but I am exhausted!

Using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newcommand{\blob}{A text which is long, but not so long  as a
  \texttt{\textbackslash lipsum}  paragraph and show the
  problem about changing the background color}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=,
                    frame hidden,
                    colback=blue!20,
                    breakable,
                    left=0pt,
                    right=0pt,
                    top=0pt,
                    bottom=4pt,
                    boxsep=0mm,
                    arc=0mm,boxrule=0pt,
                    nobeforeafter, 
                    ]
        \begin{enumerate}[resume*,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,leftmargin=!]
            \item #1
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*]
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \blob
  \item \blob
  \myitem \blob
  \item \blob
  \myitem \lipsum
  \item \blob              %% \myitem can't come at last :-(  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newcommand{\blob}{A text which is long, but not so long  as a
  \texttt{\textbackslash lipsum}  paragraph and show the
  problem about changing the background color}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,
                    backgroundcolor=blue!20,
                    leftmargin=0,
                    rightmargin=0,
                    innerleftmargin=0,
                    innerrightmargin=0,
                    skipabove=-3\itemsep,
                    skipbelow=0]
        \begin{enumerate}[resume*,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,]
            \item #1
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{mdframed}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*]
}
\begin{document}
\noindent X\hrulefill X
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \blob
  \myitem \blob
  \item \blob
  \myitem \lipsum
  \item \blob
  \item \blob
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Caveats** The code is crude and there is lot of room for improvements. Further, `\myitem` can not be the last item.

Comment: Marking as good; adding some of the trick I posted in my own answer below will do. Still I would like to see a clean way to the "last item" problem (it would be nice if `\begin{list}\end{list}` could behave as a no-op instead of erroring out).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a "workaround"--- I need to define a new environment. The follow snippet will highlight all the parts of the list `hlenum`  (admittely adding spaces --- I should mix it with the other solutions proposed here, but it's too late...) included between `\starthl` and `\stophl`. If you change the list to a `enumerate` normal one, the highlight will disappear.

`\stophl` could not be the last item in the list, but you can omit it if you want the highlight to reach the end of the list.

It is inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1702/38080) adding a `\global` in setting the counter --- which means that it will work only for the outmost list.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{framed,xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}%color of the background
\newcommand{\blob}{A text which is long, but not so long  as a
  \texttt{\textbackslash lipsum}  paragraph and show the
  problem about changing the background color}
\newcounter{glistresume}
\newif\ifintoshade
\newcommand{\realstarthl}{%
        \global\setcounter{glistresume}{\theenumi}
        \end{enumerate}
        \begin{shaded}
        \intoshadetrue
        \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{\theglistresume}
        }
\newcommand{\realstophl}{%
        \global\setcounter{glistresume}{\theenumi}
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{shaded}
        \intoshadefalse
        \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{\theglistresume}
        }
\newcommand{\starthl}{\relax}
\newcommand{\stophl}{\relax}
\newenvironment{hlenum}{%
        \intoshadefalse
        \let\starthl\realstarthl
        \let\stophl\realstophl
        \begin{enumerate}}{%
        \end{enumerate}%
        \ifintoshade \end{shaded}\fi
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{hlenum}
  \item \blob
  \starthl
  \item \blob
  \item \blob
  \stophl
  \item \blob
  \starthl
  \item \blob
  \stophl          %% you can comment these two lines
  \item last one   %% to have an highlight till the end of the list
\end{hlenum}
\end{document}
```