# Remove space between two lines

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I can't find, how to remove the space between the blocks here? (the fbox will ultimately be removed, they are just used to show the problem) And more generally, how could I debug this in order to find what is posing a problem?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{cvArray}{m}{%
  \def\currentColorIndex{0}%
  \NewDocumentCommand{\cvItem}{m+m}{%
    \ifnum\currentColorIndex=0%
      \def\currentColor{white}%
    \else%
      \def\currentColor{blue!7!white}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\currentColorIndex{int(mod(\currentColorIndex+1,2))}%
    \noindent\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=,
        frame hidden,
        colback=\currentColor,
        breakable,
        left=5pt,
        right=10pt,
        top=5pt,
        bottom=5pt,
        boxsep=0mm,
        arc=0mm,boxrule=0pt,
        nobeforeafter, 
        ]
        \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=#1]
        \item[{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{%
              \parbox[t]{#1}{\centering ##1}%
            }}] ##2
          % \item[AAA] ##2
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{tcolorbox}}
  }%
}{%
}

\begin{document}

How to remove the small space between the boxes?

\begin{cvArray}{4cm}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
\end{cvArray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or just set `\lineskip=0pt` temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like `\offinterlineskip` to switch the space between lines off:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{cvArray}{m}{%
  \def\currentColorIndex{0}%
  \NewDocumentCommand{\cvItem}{m+m}{%
    \ifnum\currentColorIndex=0%
      \def\currentColor{white}%
    \else%
      \def\currentColor{blue!7!white}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\currentColorIndex{int(mod(\currentColorIndex+1,2))}%
    \noindent\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=,
        frame hidden,
        colback=\currentColor,
        breakable,
        left=5pt,
        right=10pt,
        top=5pt,
        bottom=5pt,
        boxsep=0mm,
        arc=0mm,boxrule=0pt,
        nobeforeafter, 
        ]
        \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=#1]
        \item[{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{%
              \parbox[t]{#1}{\centering ##1}%
            }}] ##2
          % \item[AAA] ##2
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{tcolorbox}}
  }%
}{%
  \offinterlineskip\par
}

\begin{document}

How to remove the small space between the boxes?

\begin{cvArray}{4cm}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{ Blaa bla}
\end{cvArray}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh it is the first time I heard about this, I was trying to set `\baselineskip` to 0 but it was not working. Thanks!

Comment: I hope nobody minds that the tail of the "p" in the text line above bashes into the top of the box.  (Or is it that the box is doing the bashing?)

Answer (score 4):

You're overcomplicating things. Why using `\fbox` when you're doing a `tcolorbox` that has full capabilities of making a frame?

Why using a `\parbox` that's not raised and just smashed at the bottom when, obviously, you don't want multiple lines in the first argument? Why using `enumerate` for a single item?

The solution is to set `\lineskip` to the negative of the rule thickness, so the consecutive rules will overlap. However, I also reset the standard `\lineskip` in the `\parbox` for the items.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\normallineskip}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{cvArray}{m}{%
  \setlength{\normallineskip}{\lineskip}% 
  \setlength{\lineskip}{-0.4pt}% back up by the rule width
  \def\currentColorIndex{0}%
  \NewDocumentCommand{\cvItem}{m+m}{%
    \ifodd\currentColorIndex
      \def\currentColor{blue!7!white}%
    \else
      \def\currentColor{white}%
    \fi
    \edef\currentColorIndex{\inteval{\currentColorIndex+1}}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      enhanced,
      title=,
      sharp corners,
      colback=\currentColor,
      breakable,
      left=5pt,
      right=10pt,
      top=5pt,
      bottom=5pt,
      boxsep=0mm,
      arc=0mm,
      boxrule=0.4pt,
      nobeforeafter, 
    ]
    \makebox[#1]{##1}\parbox[t]{\dimeval{\linewidth-#1}}{%
      \setlength{\lineskip}{\normallineskip}%
      ##2%
    }%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }%
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{cvArray}{4cm}
  \cvItem{Foo}{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
  \cvItem{Foo}{Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{Blaa bla}
  \cvItem{Foo}{Blaa bla}
\end{cvArray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the overly complicated solution, as I sayed above, the frame is just used to show the problem (this way I can be sure that the space does not come from tcolorbox), and I will remove it. The first argument actually sometimes need multi-line items, hence the smashing, and I use enumerate because the text might be split on several pages, as advised in my previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700676/cut-a-table-because-of-newpage-inside-a-cell?noredirect=1#comment1742041_700676

Comment: @tobiasBora If you smash the first argument it will overlap what's below. The `\fbox` was among the causes of the problem, actually.

Comment: yes, I know that this could overlap, but I found no other robust method (so for now if the left part is longer than the right part, I just add new lines on the right). Oh, interesting.