# How to highlight a paragraph containing a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I'm trying to highlight an entire paragraph that contains a figure drawn with tikz. I'd like to highlight the text and also the blank space around the figure, while the figure itself should have the usual white background (the rectangle in my example means only that what's inside should not be shaded).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Some text of the main body of the document.

\paragraph{Paragraph}
Some text of the paragraph.
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node at (0,0) [rectangle,draw] { 
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5,0) node [below] {$x$};
       \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3) node [left] {$y$};
       \end{tikzpicture}};
     \end{tikzpicture} 
  \caption{The rectangle only delimits the area without shaded background; it needn't be rendered in actual paragraph.}
  \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

Some text of the paragraph. \\

Some text of the main body of the document.

\end{document}
```

I'm using [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph) as a reference.

Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example with `mdframed`. You will need the float specifier `H` from `float` package for your `figure` to avoid it floating.

I've encased your `\paragraph` in a newly defined `colorpar` environment and I've also given a white background to the `tikzpicture`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    innertopmargin=-\topskip,
    skipabove=.5\topskip,
    leftmargin=-10pt,
    rightmargin=-10pt,
    backgroundcolor=green!20,
    linewidth=0pt
]{colorpar}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Some text of the main body of the document.

\begin{colorpar}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
Some text of the paragraph.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tight background,
                      show background rectangle,
                      /tikz/background rectangle/.style={fill=white}
                     ]
     \node at (0,0) [rectangle,draw] {
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5,0) node [below] {$x$};
       \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3) node [left] {$y$};
       \end{tikzpicture}};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{The rectangle only delimits the area without shaded background; it needn't be rendered in actual paragraph.}
  \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

Some text of the paragraph.
\end{colorpar}

Some text of the main body of the document.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked out perfectly. I have just two questions: 1. Is this the usual way? Putting my figure in a node and shade the node over the background color? 2. Where can I find instructions on inserting images in posts like you did?

Comment: @PierPaolo I'm not a TikZ expert, I've learned the few things I know about it in this site. So I can't be of further help...

Answer (score 5):

By default, all `TiKZ` pictures are "transparent", what you call *usual white background* is not white, it looks like white because you draw them over a white background. Therefore when you include them over a colored background, this background color is shown through all not filled parts of the figure.

With `backgrounds` library help, it's easy to add a colored background to any `TiKZ` figure and you don't need to include it in any `node` nor `surrounding` figure, just add background definition options to `tikzpicture` environment.

Next example shows how to do it. It's similar to Karlkoeller solution but avoiding external figure and using [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) instead of `mdframed` to created the colored paragraph. It also uses `H` `float` option for not floating figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

Some text of the main body of the document.

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!30]
\paragraph{Paragraph}
Some text of the paragraph.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
       \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw, fill=white},
                           show background rectangle]
       \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5,0) node [below] {$x$};
       \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3) node [left] {$y$};
       \fill[blue] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
       \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{The rectangle only delimits the area without shaded background; it needn't be rendered in actual paragraph.}
  \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

Some text of the paragraph. \\
\end{tcolorbox}

Some text of the main body of the document.

\end{document}
```

[image]