# Grey box just as in Mathjax

Tags: formatting

How could I get a grey box in latex like the one I get on math.stackexchange when I type > to start a paragraph?

Comment: which package are you using?  `color`, `framed`, `tcolorbox`, or something else?

Comment: If I read this right, that's not MathJaX, that's Markdown.

Comment: @Thruston None of them yet, because I don't know exactly how that would work. So I also don't have any specific preferece for any of those.

Comment: Well any of those packages will let you create grey shaded boxes, so if you pick one - `colorbox` provided by the `color` package is probably the simplest - and have a go, and if you get stuck you could then update your Q with an [example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for people to work on.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That could be true, I am not quite familiar with all those 'languages'. Do you know how I could get the same effect in Latex?

Comment: @Thruston Ok I got the colorbox with the colorpackage to work now, but the color grey that I get is way darker than the standard color that you for instance used in your comments. Is there a way to get that same color?

Comment: Also, the colorbox by far doesn't work as easily as the boxes that you can use on the stackex websites. For instance, if I want to include multiple paragraphs into one block of 'gray', everything gets messed up.

Comment: This [page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) tells you how to mix your own colours.

Comment: @abc please take a look at the possibilities listed in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59342/3954) to [How to highlight an entire paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59340/3954).

Comment: You can put a whole `minipage` inside a `colorbox`.   But at this stage you really should give us an example!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks a lot, that might be what I'm looking for. I'll try it out and post back.

Comment: @Thruston I'll first try out Gonzalo's suggestion, if that doesn't work I'll post an example

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The suggestions on your link solve my problem. Thanks :)! Except for that I'd like a lighter color of grey still (like the one on stackex).

Comment: @abc you can change `blue!20` to `gray!20` (or similar). Since the problem seems solved, do you consider this question can be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I used the following command from @Thruston's link: \definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}. Now everything works fine. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes it can be closed if you wish. (Though I think it's not an exact duplicate so some people might still benifit from it later).

Comment: @abc if it's not an exact duplicate, perhaps you could edit your question and add some code showing what you've tried and what problems are still present.