# Lyx: what do if 'Allow page Breaks' is not available?

Tags: lyx, page-breaking, minipage

I'm beginner in LyX and I have a problem. In 'LyX: box' the option "allow page breaks' is not available. What can I do?

Answer (score 6):

LyX's Insert > Box options all set *unbreakable* boxes. You'll have to create a custom inset to manage something the provides *breakable* boxes. One package that provides this is [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed). So, let's set up a custom inset that uses `mdframed`:

1. Set up the environment that you're going to use. For this, add the following to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble:

   ```
   \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

   \newmdenv[
     hidealllines=true,
     backgroundcolor=blue!20,
     innerleftmargin=3pt,
     innerrightmargin=3pt,
     leftmargin=-3pt,
     rightmargin=-3pt
   ]{shadedbox}
   ```

   The above code loads the `mdframed` package and also sets up an environment called `shadedbox` with the given parameters. You can read the [`mdframed` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) to see exactly the meaning of them all, and redefine it to make it your own. I chose an example from [How to highlight an entire paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59340/5764).
2. Now set up Document > Settings... > Local Layout that uses the environment defined above:

   ```
   Format 60

   InsetLayout Flex:Shaded_Box
     LyXType           custom
     LabelString       "Shaded Box"
     LatexType     Environment
     LatexName     shadedbox
     Decoration        Classic
     MultiPar              true
     CustomPars        true
     ResetsFont        true
     LabelFont
       Color               foreground
       Size                Small
     EndFont
   End
   ```

   This adds "Shaded Box" to your Insert > Custom Inset menu item:

   [image]
3. Use it like you mean it!

   [image]

You'll have to understand how to change the settings of the environment to make it suit your needs. One could also add an optional argument to make small, local modifications if needed.