# Alternating item background colors in labeling without using a table?

Tags: lists

I'd like to take the following code, and make the rows alternate background colors, **without** using a table, as that breaks twocolumn, and without using multicol, as that breaks floats. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\newcounter{foonum}
\newcommand{\roll}{
  \stepcounter{foonum}
  \arabic{foonum}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{\textbf{roll}}
\item [\textbf{roll}] \textbf{item}
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\item [\roll] Item
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Using @Pouya 's answer, this is what I have come up with. But I need to find a way to reduce or eliminate the huge gaps between items.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{foonum}
\newcommand{\roll}{
  \stepcounter{foonum}
  \arabic{foonum}
}


\newcommand{\AltItem}[1]{%
    \ifodd \value{foonum} 
         \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,
                          backgroundcolor=blue!20,
                          innerleftmargin=1.5pt,
                          innerrightmargin=10pt,
                          leftmargin=-18pt,
                          innertopmargin=-6pt,
                          innerbottommargin=6pt]
           \item [\roll] \hangindent=15pt #1%
         \end{mdframed}
    \else  
         \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,
                          backgroundcolor=red!20,
                          innerleftmargin=1.5pt,
                          innerrightmargin=10pt,
                          leftmargin=-18pt,
                          innertopmargin=-6pt,
                          innerbottommargin=6pt]
           \item [\roll] \hangindent=15pt #1%
         \end{mdframed}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{\textbf{roll}}
\item [\textbf{roll}] \textbf{item}
\AltItem {This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence.}
\AltItem {This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence. This is a longer sentence.}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Using a breakable tabular might be simpler. See [multicolumn long table or enumeration](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13895)

Comment: @AlanMunn multicols breaks floats, which is a requirement listed in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a no-so-elegant solution and has lots of room for improvement. It takes your counter, `foonum`, and checks to see if the value is odd or not and based on that sets the background color.

There are two caveats: 1. As it is, you should *renew* the item command and 2. The highlighting itself needs adjustments. For the later, please refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59342/22492) comprehensive answer and try for yourself. My answer just an starting point...

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{foonum}
\newcommand{\roll}{
  \stepcounter{foonum}
  \arabic{foonum}
}


\newcommand{\AltItem}[1]{%
    \ifodd \value{foonum} 
        %% test:
        % \textcolor{red}{\item [\roll] #1}%

        %% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59342/22492

        %% -----------1--------------
        % \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20,innerleftmargin=3pt,innerrightmargin=3pt]%,leftmargin=-20pt,rightmargin=-3pt,skipbelow=10pt,skipabove=10pt
        %   \item [\roll] #1%
        % \end{mdframed}

        %% -----------2--------------
        \begin{shaded}
            \item [\roll] #1%
        \end{shaded}

        %% -----------3--------------
        % \noindent\adjustbox{bgcolor=blue!20,minipage=[t]{\linewidth}}{\item [\roll] #1}
    \else  
        \item [\roll] #1%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{\textbf{roll}}
\item [\textbf{roll}] \textbf{item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\AltItem {Item}
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will accept this answer if I can figure out how to adjust the boxes...

Comment: @raevol, yeah that needs some work. Give a shot at solution marked by a comment line `------1------`. That has several options that could you with.

Comment: I updated my question with my progress. I've got it to a reasonable solution, but there's pretty large gaps between the items... is there a way to reduce that?