# alternate background color for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, color, colorbox

I am trying to get alternate background color for bibliography, with `AtBeginBebliography`, as shown(Please note, `\IF_COUNTER_IS_ODD` does not have any meaning, it is just to show, I want orange `\colorbox` for odd number item, and the normal white background for even item.). This is a `mwe`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxbibnames=99,
  citestyle=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{% 
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\IF_COUNTER_IS_ODD% 
        {\colorbox{orange}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
        {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
    }}
\AtEveryBibitem{\IF_COUNTER_IS_ODD
    {\colorbox{orange}}
    {}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**mwe.bib**

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

Comment: I think attempts to use LaTeX box macros like `\colorbox` are doomed, because the way `biblatex` produces bibliography entries does not lend itself to absorbing the entry as an argument of a macro. But there is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457084/35864. An alternative if you don't like that might be possible with `lua-ul` but will need you to compile your document with LuaLaTeX (which may or may not be an issue for you).

Comment: Come to think of it, the `lua-ul` solution will look more like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547414/35864, which is probably not quite what you have in mind.

Comment: @moewe: nope, the solution is looking like your first reply, which is **exactly** what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.