# color background in float

Tags: floats, color

Here is my code to create an info box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\floatstyle{ruled} 
\newfloat{InfoBox}{h}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{InfoBox}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{Point 1} \blindtext

\medskip
\textbf{Point 2} \blindtext

\medskip
\textbf{Point 3} \blindtext
\vspace{0.5cm}
\caption{This a caption}
\end{InfoBox}

\end{document}
```

How could I add a background color between the two lines that contain the main text? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might be interested in tcolorbox.

Comment: @José what do you consider as the main text?

Comment: Every text line but the caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here below is a solution based on this : [How to highlight an entire paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph)

**Mechanism**

I created a new float style by using the same way as the `float` package does for the 'ruled' style.
Then I used the `framed` package and its `snugshade` environment to create the color box.

It looks like this:

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

% Mandatory package
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

% To change the color
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!20}
%\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}

% For test only
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}

% Creation of a new floatstyle 'toto'
\makeatletter
    \newcommand\floatc@toto[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1} #2\par}
    \newcommand\fs@toto{%
        \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@toto
        \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
        \def\@fs@mid{%
            \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
            \begin{snugshade}
        }%
        \def\@fs@post{%
            \end{snugshade}
            \kern2pt\hrule\relax
        }%
        \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{toto} 
\newfloat{InfoBox}{h}{}


\begin{document}

    \begin{InfoBox}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \textbf{Point 1} \blindtext

        \medskip
        \textbf{Point 2} \blindtext

        \medskip
        \textbf{Point 3} \blindtext
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \caption{This a caption}
    \end{InfoBox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!