Is there a way to have a shape with curved corners that contains text?

Something like this. I am really bad with art on digital or paper, and I want to use that to latex to write an article thing because its more programmatical which I am good with, and because its simpler than rememebering everything within CSS

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome. // Using Tikz you could place a \node with text. Its default shape is rectangle (put draw into the nodes options). You can also set its options to rounded corners. If you need a more fancy shape, put a node with draw=none AND draw the fancy shape in the same place.

Have a look at tcolorbox package.

Have a look at tcolorbox documentation, page number 238, if not so, provide more clear on your requirement

This question is similar to: How to draw frame with rounded corners around box. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph

I'm not entirely sure what you want exactly. However, if you're looking for a shape that resembles a box with rounded corners and want to place content inside it, I believe the best solution is to use the tcolorbox package, as @NBur mentioned in the comments of your post. To make it practical, I'll provide a small MWE below. This example demonstrates how to create a custom environment, which you can call whenever you need to use that custom-shaped box. Here's how it looks:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{importantbox}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        colback=gray!20,
        colframe=gray!50,
        arc=2pt,
        boxrule=1pt,
        left=15pt,
        right=15pt,
        top=10pt,
        bottom=10pt
    ]%
}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\blindtext

\begin{importantbox}
    This is my custom \textbf{box}!

    And this is my super important text here.
\end{importantbox}

\end{document}

It produces the following:

Note that you can easily change the values for the rounded corners, padding, and colors in the tcolorbox declaration within the newly created environment.
Hope it helped.

Like this:

Code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (7,3);
        \fill[gray!30](.1,.1) circle(.2);
        \fill[gray!30](6.9,.1) circle(.2);
        \node at (3.5,1.5) () {\huge Some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

